# Byte[] to char[]

Tags: java, char, byte

I am in a requirement of display raw byte data in char form, there are some issue I am stuck like for example [ 1, 32, -1, -1 ] ( byte data ) which when converted into char comes as [1, 3, 2, -, 1, - ,1]

My requirement

[ 1, 32, -1, -1 ] in char format.

Intailly

I used the command

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < byte1.length;i++){
    buffer.append(byte1[i]);
    }
char[] c = buffer.toString().toCharArray();
```

Didn't serve my requirement.

Then I used

```
char dig = (char)(((int)'0')+ (-32));

it gave an invalid output
```

Kindly help in my requirement. Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you like a number like `-1` to be represented as a character? Do you literally want the `-` sign only?

Comment: Exactly I have no idea, but sadly that’s my requirement.... Any alternative method is also cool....

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html `char` can only represent one single character, so `32` is impossible one char. so is -1. 32 and -1 need two `char`s.

Comment: Do you mean byte[] not Byte[]?

Comment: I suppose you could just cast the signed to unsigned bytes; but you will end up with "ASCII" codes above 127 which isn't going to look pretty... Also, there will be control codes (for example, the number `12` will clear the screen.). I can't see this is a sensible "requirement", unless you allow for "escaping" all characters not in the range 0x20 - 0x7F.

Comment: @ adam, yes its byte[]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need to stick to strings, use array of char array, first append extra 0 in case its short and If your data is in byte format, use `bytes1.toString()` and then something like this,

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] byte1 = {"2","45","56","1"};
        for (int i = 0; i < byte1.length; i++) {
            if(byte1[i].length()<2){
                byte1[i] = "0"+byte1[i];
            }
        }
        char[][] chr = new char[5][10];
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < byte1.length;i++){
               chr[i] = byte1[i].toCharArray();
        }


    for (int i = 0; i < chr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(chr[i]);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a printable representation:

```
String readable = Arrays.toString(byte1);
```

But as stated you need a string Array like thing for this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will work for you:

```
byte byte1[] = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 33, 92, 45, 127, -5, -23};
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < byte1.length;i++){
      if (byte1[i] >= 32 && byte1[i] != 92 && byte1[i] != 127) buffer.append((char)byte1[i]);
      else {
        String temp;
        if (byte1[i] == 92) {
          buffer.append("\\\\");
        }
        else {
          temp = String.format("\\0x%02x", byte1[i]);
          buffer.append(temp);
        }
      }
    }
System.out.println(buffer);
```

This will produce the output:

```
Hello!\\-\0x7f\0xfb\0xe9
```

The "representable" characters will be printed normally, the others are turned into a "escaped" hex code. The `\` gets special treatment - if you want to show hex codes with an escape backslash, then you need a backslash to escape a backslash (and to get `\\` in the output, you need `"\\\\"` in the code...

I also trapped the character value `127` separately since I didn't want a `DEL` in the string - not sure what effect that would have depending on the environment.

If your requirement is indeed exactly as you describe, you might consider the following code (which produces exactly what you asked for):

```
byte byte1[] = {1, 32, -1, -1};
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append("[");
for(int i = 0; i < byte1.length - 1;i++){
  buffer.append(String.format("%d,", byte1[i]));
}
buffer.append(String.format("%d]", byte1[byte1.length - 1]));
System.out.println(buffer);
```

Output:

```
[1,32,-1,-1]
```

Notice - since some numbers require more than one character, you end up with a string that is more than 4 characters long. There is no way around that.

Comment: The second is the same what `Arrays.toString(byte[])` produces?

Answer (score -1):

Since a char field is litteraly 1 character, there is no way to store 2 characters in a char field.